# error while informatica installation 9.6.1-command to create domain failed

Tags: informatica, failed-installation

**getting error while installing informatica server installation**
given my **log file**

please help me

**log file::**

Exit Code : 1

OutPut : #
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=7964, tid=8156

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  0x0000000000000000

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
C:\Informatica\9.6.1\isp\bin\hs_err_pid7964.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Informatica have its own java binary and all required files. So, i think there is some steps you are missing. Can you please check few things and try to reinstall -

- While installing infa, make sure you provide correct JAVA JDBC URL(probably step 58) info of the database. Check JDBC parameters like host, port, DB Name etc. and MaxPoolstatement etc should be default. And make sure 'Test connection' is successful.
- Make sure JAVA_HOME is set properly. And INFA_JAVA_HOME is not set before installation and configuration.
- Check Java vesion of host server. Existing version may cause issue here.
- Make sure you are using 32 or 64 bit version of all software. starting from informatica to java version that's already installed(to be on safe side).

If you still facing issues please post the logfile that installation process generates. YOu should get that in C:\Informatica\9.6.1\

Koushik